# How can I print a properly sized passport photograph using Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, printing

It's time to renew my passport, and I thought I'd save some money by taking a self portrait and then printing it at home. I made the self portrait and edited it down to the required 2 inch by 2 inch size. However, when I tried to print the picture from my Windows 7 computer, the computer automatically re-sizes the picture. I also tried the contact sheet printing option, but that isn't large enough. How can I get my passport photo printed at the proper size?

Comment: Check your print dialog options for any "scale" settings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are printing through Windows Photo Viewer, you won't get the proper size you want. Alternatively, many people use Photoshop for this task. If you don't have it, insert the image in Word or PowerPoint and set the size if you have to.

If you don't have any Office software, use a free image viewer like [IrfanView](http://www.irfanview.com/). Its printing dialogue box offers options to retain the image dimensions or resize it to your preference. Open your image with IrfanView and hit `CTRL+P`. Grouped under `Print size`, find the option `Custom` and set your width and height. Untick `Aspect ratio` if you want to resize freely. Click `Print` and enjoy saving some money :)

Comment: Don't have Office or Photoshop. I had tried editing with GIMP on my Linux computer (which isn't able to print to my printer, due to driver issues), but when I transferred the file to the Windows system, the OS still overrode the photo's size. However, IrfanView worked. Thanks!

Comment: @GreenMatt Glad to be of help :) Besides printing, IrfanView can crop, convert, resize, view GIF, browse media files, correct image's wrong file extension, paste printed screen, acquire from scanner, apply simple image processing, etc. I'm not affiliated with the developer, but I really like how small this programme is with many functions..